# f:ajax listener isn't called

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

I've got a problem considering JSF and AJAX.
I am trying to update some customer details after a visitor inserts the customer id.

Firstly, a excerpt from the xhmtl code:

```
    <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGrid columns ="2" border="1" id="customer_grid">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{mbean_msg.reservation_lblCustomerNo}" for = "customer_id"/>
            <h:inputText id = "customer_id" value="#{reservationHandler.customer.customer_id}">
                <f:ajax listener="{reservationHandler.autocompleteCustomerDetails}" 
                    render="customer_grid" />
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel value="#{mbean_msg.reservation_lblLastname}" for="lastname"/>
            <h:inputText id="lastname" value="#{reservationHandler.customer.lastname}" required ="true" 
                requiredMessage="#{error_msg.errmsgLastname}" validator="#{reservationHandler.validateCustomer}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="#{mbean_msg.reservation_lblFirstname}" for="firstname"/>
            <h:inputText id="firstname" value="#{reservationHandler.customer.firstname}" required ="true"
                requiredMessage="#{error_msg.errmsgFirstname}" validator="#{reservationHandler.validateCustomer}"/>
```

The listener method is implemented within my java file (ReservationHandler.java) like that:

```
public void autocompleteCustomerDetails(){
      System.out.println("Auto Complete"); // for testing
}
```

Basically I am trying to call the method *autocompleteCustomerDetails* with the Listener. Unfortunately this method is never called. Anyways, the render seems to work just fine, since the other *inputTexts* update themselves (visibly).

Does anybody have an idea, why the listener isn't called?

Comment: what scope is your `ReservationHandler` bean ? also try changing its signature into `public void autocompleteCustomerDetails(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev){}`

Comment: I also tried it with AjaxBehaviorEvent before and it makes no difference. My bean is session scoped.

Comment: does it work for you if you add `event="keyup"` to your `<f:ajax` ?

Comment: Is the missing `#` in the `listener="#{...}"` a careless typo during preparing the question or is it also missing in the real code?

Comment: Thank you, it was just a silly typo. Right now the listener works, but I receive a "method not found" exception.

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems in the code shown so far:

First,

```html
<f:ajax listener="{reservationHandler.autocompleteCustomerDetails}" />
```

this isn't a valid EL expression. EL expessions have the form of `#{}`, not `{}`. Fix it accordingly:

```html
<f:ajax listener="#{reservationHandler.autocompleteCustomerDetails}" />
```

---

Second,

```
public void autocompleteCustomerDetails() {
```

this isn't a valid default signature of a method expression for `<f:ajax listener>`. The [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) clearly tells the following:

> signature must match `public void processAjaxBehavior(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException`.

So, you forgot the argument. Add it accordingly. The `throws` declaration isn't mandatory for unchecked exceptions, so we can just leave it out.

```
public void autocompleteCustomerDetails(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
```

Or, if you actually intend to get rid of the argument, then you should put parentheses in the EL method expression:

```html
<f:ajax listener="#{reservationHandler.autocompleteCustomerDetails()}" />
```

Note that this works only if your container supports EL 2.2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I adjusted the source code like you suggested but I still receive a "method not found" exception. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart?

Comment: @ViswanathL: how exactly is that related to a "method not found" exception? Please stop shooting around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<f:ajax listener="{reservationHandler.autocompleteCustomerDetails()}" 
                render="customer_grid" />
```

or change the method to:
    getAutoCompleteCustomerDetails

just for testing...

Anyhow, you´re not allowed to use any jsf's components library? Like primefaces ?
It gets the job done in such a easy way...

Anyhow, with primefaces I would do that like this:

```
 <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{prospectoRadarController.atualizarRadar(data)}" update=":mainForm:painelRadar" />
```

Another guess would be, add the execute="@this" to the ajax flag...

Sorry, those are all wild guesses, but I really want to help.
PLease feedback!